# Pandas - How to GroupBy from Particular Time of Day Every 24 hours?

Tags: python, pandas

My data has two columns - first is TxnAmount, second is TxnDate ( which has date & time in string format)

```
 **TxnAmount**      **TxnDate**

 100                '2018-04-01 19:12:26'

 135                '2018-04-01 17:03:50'

 210                '2018-04-01 14:37:17'

 70                 '2018-04-02 12:24:49'

 250                '2018-04-02 09:56:18'
```

Here is my code, which is able to sum ( day wise)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('File.csv')
df["TxnDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TxnDate"])
df.set_index(df["TxnDate"],inplace=True)
df['TxnAmount'].resample('D', how='sum')
```

But, **I need the sum to be from 6:00 AM to 6:00 AM interval**. The code I assume by default sums according to stand 0:00 AM to 0:00 interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `base` argument in [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.set_index("TxnDate").resample(rule='24H', closed='left', label='left', base=6).sum()

                     TxnAmount
TxnDate                       
2018-04-01 06:00:00        445
2018-04-02 06:00:00        320
```

Data:

```
df = {'TxnAmount': {0: 100, 1: 135, 2: 210, 3: 70, 4: 250},
      'TxnDate': {0: Timestamp('2018-04-01 19:12:26'),
                  1: Timestamp('2018-04-01 17:03:50'),
                  2: Timestamp('2018-04-01 14:37:17'),
                  3: Timestamp('2018-04-02 12:24:49'),
                  4: Timestamp('2018-04-02 09:56:18')}}
```